# Rotation using Panolens causes panorama image issues

Tags: javascript, html, panoramas, 360-panorama-viewer

Im currently trying to create a website where you can switch between two panorama images with a button click. Im using Panolens and their viewer. I want to make sure the rotation of the two images are aligned so when i switch between the two I will see how its different. For context, its our home before and after renovations.

The photos seem to cause some issues when trying to rotate the photos. They load and there are some black spots on the photo, and then they disappear. I have a photo of what happens. [Result of rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTEcj.png)

For reference, this is some of code for the panoramas I have on the website, including the rotations adjustment:

```
//Starting rotations for second images
    const rotations = [0,-Math.PI/4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

    //Adding the panoramas to their viewer
    for (let i = 0; i < viewers.length; i++) {
        images[i][1].rotation.y = rotations[i]; //Adding rotations
        viewers[i].OrbitControls.noZoom = true; //Remove zoom from them
        viewers[i].add(images[i][0])
        viewers[i].add(images[i][1])
    }
```

I have multiple panorama viewers and images, and its only the rotation that causes issues

I have tried using yaw and pitch, the rotation component and other ways. But if there isn't a way to fix this, no worries.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)